# How to make user menu in wordpress, different for each user

Tags: wordpress

I got some question regarding WordPress, I wanted to know is there any way I can achieve this type of scenario.

1. Users can buy a photo, their own photos. For example, user A can buy only a photo with their face in it.
2. Same goes for User B.
3. In each of the photos that have been bought, they can see their own on their dashboard. For example, link-example.com/home will show them the menu, which will redirect to their own photos that have been bought. (Concept like a password-protected page, need to enter the password, then only the content will show up.)
4. Each user will be provided a password, and will redirect to the page. And the menu will be different for each user. (Users can be many)
   Are there any plugins available to achieve this issue?

[Click here to view the interface draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnxfJ.png)

The idea is kinda like this website,

http://pret-a-portrait.net/

I hope the question is clear as I provide the photos of the concept

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce has the eCommerce side of things to be able to take payments and setup your photos as a product. It's free and easier to setup than your toaster.

The documentation with extending it is also very well written and I personally have gone to town on a `my-account` page in the past so anything you can dream up is possible with the right research. I think giving it a go and just having a `Google` of things like `adding a tab to my-account woocommerce` will make things more clear for you.

https://woocommerce.com/